# Vimeo Api PHP Setup issue

Tags: php, wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm following the starter guide to implement the Vimeo API on a website using wordpress (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start) bug I have an issue on very basic code :

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 $pathToAutoload = get_template_directory().'/vendor/autoload.php';
 require $pathToAutoload;
 use Vimeo\Vimeo;

 $client = new Vimeo(
  "myClientId",
  "myClientSecret",
  "myAccessToken"
 );

 $response = $client->request('/tutorial', array(), 'GET');
 print_r($response);
?>
```

I get this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /Users/Robin/Documents/Works/mySite/v4/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php on line 88
```

It looks like the error comes from the library itself.
There is the code at this line where the error appear :

```
public function request($url, $params = array(), $method = 'GET', $json_body = true, array $headers = array()): array
```

Any idea how to debug it ?

(I'm using MAMP Pro and PHP 5.6.37)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Vimeo library you must have PHP >= 7.1.0, please check requirements on url below

https://packagist.org/packages/vimeo/vimeo-api

or try older version (if it's still working) which is compatible with PHP >= 5.3.0),

https://packagist.org/packages/vimeo/vimeo-api#2.0.5